# Invalid display resolution while using TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT of WindowManager

Tags: android

I'm using `WindowManager.LayoutParams` class using `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` to get an activity on top of everything. Everything is working fine except the display resolution which appears to be magnified, and therefore I'm not able to see the full content of the layout.

Here is the screenshot

[Layout Snapshot](http://www33.speedyshare.com/QwJYp/download/Screenshot-2015-01-07-00-19-55.png)

**(Extremely sorry for not uploading the image directly due to my low reputation as I'm new to StackOverflow)**

My code for WindowManager.LayoutParams is

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;

        wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        mTopView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.block_device, null);
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        wm.addView(mTopView, params);
```

I also tried `WRAP_CONTENT` instead of `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`, but it showed an `IllegalStateException` that `ActionBarView` can only be used with `MatchParent`.

Any fixes that I can try out???

Answer (score 0):

In 5.1 as part of extra security system_alert kind of dialog, which writes on top of another application is UI is deprecated. In my application I had one activity which had system_alert dialog it was working until 5.0 but in 5.1 not working (after `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission also its not working). I referred androidxref U can see in the following link *http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java#1639*

They will check and throw the exception if app is trying to write on the window of other application
Finally we had to redesign the application to not use System alert kind of dialog
Refer the following code snippet for sample code...

```
    String message = getString(R.string.progress_message);        
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    mProgressDialog.setTitle(R.string.progress_title_message);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage(message);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(mProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.show();`
```